# password validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

I need to match a password field using javascript with the following requirements:

1. Should be alpha numaric with at least one special character.
2. no spaces to be allowed
3. should be minimum 10 char and max 20 chars.
4. No repeate of char more than 2 times.
5. ~,'.:;^| are not allowed

I have a regex
var password = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{10,20}$/;
 how can i solve this?

Comment: var password = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{10,20}$/;

Comment: I wouldn't force such passwort constraints on the user. Here is a quite thorough analysis of password strengths: https://tech.dropbox.com/2012/04/zxcvbn-realistic-password-strength-estimation/

Comment: @SachinMalmanchi pls check whether my regex worked for you

Answer (score 1):

This might be the required regex

```
^(?=.*[!@#$%^&])(?!.*(.).*\1.*\1)[A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&|]{10,20}$
```

`(?=.*[!@#$%^&])` ensures at least one occurrence of the listed characters.

`(?!.*(.).*\1.*\1)` ensures no character is repeated more than twice.

`[A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&|]{10,20}` matches 10-20 occurrence of characters from the character class.

Comment: @Loamhoof where would it fail?pls give example

Comment: I've deleted my comment right after posting it as it was wrong, sorry.

Comment: Though you should still change `(?=.*[!@#$%^&].*)` as it's pretty bad regarding performance and the last .* is unnecessary. Still, with such small strings it doesn't really matter I guess.

Comment: @Loamhoof if performance is a concern, regex should be avoided altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I would write separate rules (probably using regex for all of them - for consistency - unless performance is a great concern) that each relate directly to a rule on your list.

### The code

```
var pw = "asddfak@kjg";

/* Should be alpha numaric with at least one special character. */
console.log(null !== pw.match(/[@+#$]/));

/* no spaces to be allowed */
console.log(null !== pw.match(/^\S+$/));

/* should be minimum 10 char and max 20 chars. */
console.log(null !== pw.match(/^.{10,20}$/));

/* No repeate of char more than 2 times. */
console.log(null === pw.match(/(.)(.*\1){2}/));

/* ~,'.:;^| are not allowed */
console.log(null !== pw.match(/^[^~,'.:;^|]+$/));
```

Although it is possible to make the regex more concise, I think it is much more maintainable to make the rules more literal to your intent. If performance is a significant issue (usually not for this kind of thing) then I would avoid regex, and implement the rules using string methods.

### Regex Explained

```
/           // start regex pattern
[           // open character class
@+#$        // match one of these `special` characters
]           // close character class
/           // end regex pattern 

/           // start regex pattern
^           // start matched string
\S+         // one or more (`+`) not spaces (`\S`)
$           // end matched string
/           // end regex pattern 

/           // start regex pattern
^           // start matched string
.{10,20}    // between 10 and 20 of any character (`.`)
$           // end matched string
/           // end regex pattern 

/           // start regex pattern
(.)         // any character captured as group 1
(.*\1){2}   // followed by zero or more of anything (`\.*`) and then the captured group 1 (`\1`) two times (`{2}`)
/           // end regex pattern 

/           // start regex pattern
^           // start matched string
[           // open character class
^~,'.:;^|   // not (`^`) one of these characters
]+          // close character class
$           // end matched string
/           // end regex pattern
```

***p.s. you should keep a lot of comments with regex you use, because unlike books, they are much easier written than read***

Comment: `[^\s]` can be replaced with `\S`

Comment: @NaveedS updated - thanks. Any more improvements? I do like a good regex!

Comment: @Billy Moon : how can we write with a regular expression for this?? please reply me

Comment: @SachinMalmanchi my solution uses a regular expression for each rule you defined. You then need to check your password against each rule. My demo code shows you the output form a valid password in the javascript console. If you change the input to an invalid password, one or more of the rules will fail, in my demo code showing `false`. You should write a wrapper function, including my demo code, that accepts a password, and returns true for a valid password, or handles errors if it is invalid. You should inform the user which rule was broken if the password is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
/^(?=.*?[!@#$%^&])(?:([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&])(?!.*?\1.*?\1)){10,20}$/
```

(if by repeat more than 2 times you mean the same character can't appear thrice)

**Explanation:**
*1st condition*: at the very beginning, we'll go through the whole string a first time until we find a special character, as soon as we have it, we stop, if we don't, it fails ([Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)): `(?=.*?[!@#$%^&])`
*2nd condition*: nothing to do, `[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&]` doesn't allow spaces anyway
*3rd condition*: quantifier: `{10,20}`
*4th condition*: the subtle one: as we get through the string, for each character captured, we check the it's not repeated twice more (same source): `(?!.*?\1.*?\1)`
*5th condition*: same as whitespaces

Comment: can you give the explanation for this?

Comment: @Loamhoof where would my regex fail?pls give example

Comment: @SachinMalmanchi of course it's not because * is not in the list of special characters you "gave".

Answer (score 0):

based on your 5 things in your requirements this is exact pattern you need

```
^(?=.*[!@#$%^&])(?!.*(.).*\1.*\1)[^\s~,'.:;^|]{10,20}$
```

Comment: can you give the example which satisfy your condition and failed in this pattern

Comment: test in this site with my regex its working with sachin*10&M http://regexpal.com/